# meaning of in_qsize and out_qsize in gensim word2vec log files

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am running word2vec models in gensim. I don't understand 2 metrics (in_qsize/out_qsize) reported by the log file. I've spent a bit of time searching and can't find an explanation. Here is a sample from my log files:

```
2020-04-17 21:04:09,032 : INFO : EPOCH 5 - PROGRESS: at 68.67% examples, 657466 words/s, in_qsize 18, out_qsize 1
2020-04-17 21:04:10,038 : INFO : EPOCH 5 - PROGRESS: at 68.92% examples, 657527 words/s, in_qsize 20, out_qsize 0
2020-04-17 21:04:11,078 : INFO : EPOCH 5 - PROGRESS: at 69.14% examples, 657513 words/s, in_qsize 20, out_qsize 1
2020-04-17 21:04:12,136 : INFO : EPOCH 5 - PROGRESS: at 69.39% examples, 657458 words/s, in_qsize 18, out_qsize 1
2020-04-17 21:04:13,139 : INFO : EPOCH 5 - PROGRESS: at 69.68% examples, 657687 words/s, in_qsize 17, out_qsize 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_qsize` and `out_qsize` are the lengths of two internal queues used by the code to send work to the worker-threads, and receive results.

Their names in the source code are `job_queue` and `progress_queue`, but you can also find that, and more about them, by searching through the source code for the lines that print `in_qsize` and `out_qsize`.

In general they are a sufficiently internal detail that most users won't need to care about their values – unless debugging some atypical performance issues. In some cases it could add a little more understanding to how different choices of corpus-preparation, `workers` value, or other parameters are affecting througput. But in general such optimization can just involve trying lots of different values to see which in practice achieves the best throughput, without caring about those internal queue sizes.

Comment: Thank you @gojomo ! Should I be concerned that my out_qsize is much smaller than my in_qsize?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you could try other counts of `workers`, & see if throughput during the multi-threaded training improves. (That may be an indicator that the corpus-reading master thread is getting ahead of the worker threads.) Unfortunately, even if you have 16 or more CPU cores, the optimal throughput is often reached somewhere in the 6-12 workers range, leaving many cores underutilized due to Python threading issues. (Using the newer `corpus_file` option can better-utilize all cores, if your pre-tokenized input is available as a single file, one 'sentence' per line.)